# Is it possible to draw a line outside rect bounds in draw(_ rect: CGRect) function in a UIView subclass that is backed by a CATiledLayer?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, drawrect, catiledlayer

I have a UIView subclass that is backed by a CATiledLayer, where I override draw(_ rect: CGRect) function for custom drawing. Is it possible to draw a line outside rect bounds?

Comment: Usually the drawing context is set up to clip drawing to the specified rectangle and any drawing outside of that rectangle will not be visible. I'm not sure what happens if the view's `clipsToBounds` is set to false. Why not do a simple test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a test, and no, it seems that you can't draw outside of the rect provided in the call to the `draw(_:)` function.

I created a custom Subclass of UIView that overrides `draw(_:)`:

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let drawRect = rect.insetBy(dx: -10, dy: -10)
        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: drawRect)
        UIColor.yellow.setFill()
        path.fill()
    }
}
```

And then I added a CustomView to my storyboard. I set up the view in the storyboard with a `layer.borderWidth = 2` so you could see the border of the view, and this is what was drawn:

[image]

My `draw(_:)` method tried to inset the draw rect by (-10,-10), which makes the rectangle bigger, but no drawing is visible outside of the bounds set in the storyboard.

Comment: Dear Duncan thank you for your answer and sorry for the delayed reply. `clipsToBounds` will not do any difference if set to `False`. Indeed, you cannot draw outside of the rect. I was wondering whether there is a way to overcome this characteristic so as to be able to draw outside the rect.

Comment: You probably could by manipulating the clipping area of the graphics context, but you shouldn't do that. The design behind drawRect is that the system may mask all but a small portion of your view's frame rect because only a small portion needs to be redrawn, and when you draw, the drawing gets clipped. If you override that masking mechanism you could "step on" parts of the screen that don't belong to your view and cause bad side-effects.

Comment: Did you just accept and upvote my answer today, almost 2 years later?!? Better late than never I guess...

Comment: I have recently posted another question, and I have realised that this is the correct thing to do when an answer is the one I was searching for :)